# How to make the shell execute only external echo, not the builtin one?

Tags: shell, c, echo

I have a C program which uses `system()` library function. Below is the source code.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{ 
    //Some code
    system("echo Hello World");
    //some code
    return 0;
}
```

Before running this C program I changed `$PATH` so that  `/home/user1/bin/echo` would be executed instead of `/bin/echo`

```
export PATH="/home/user1/bin"
```

However when I ran the C program it did not execute `/home/user1/bin/echo`.

Is it because `echo` is a `shell built-in` so shell did not attempt to find `echo` in `$PATH`?

If so, is there any changes I can make in the shell before I run this program, so that `echo` will be searched in `$PATH` instead of using the built-in `echo`.

Comment: Why don't you just copy the source somewhere where you can edit it, change it and recompile? You won't find a shell-based answer.

Comment: @terdon My objective is to show that this program is vulnerable. I want to make my version of `echo` to be run instead of a `built-in echo` or `/bin/echo`.

Comment: well, you might have to find a new objective then. The builtin of `sh` will apparently always be run. Find something else to attack.

Comment: `env` is almost everywhere, so how about `env echo`?

Answer (score 4):

`command` bypasses functions, but not shell builtins. The safest way would be use the full path:

```
system("/home/user1/bin/echo Hello world!")
```

If you can't do that, try the `exec` builtin:

```
system("exec echo Hello World!")
```

For example:

```
$ cat foo.c       
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{ 
    //Some code
    system("exec echo --help");
    system("command echo --help");
    system("echo --help");
    //some code
    return 0;
}  
$ gcc -o foo foo.c
$ ./foo
Usage: echo [SHORT-OPTION]... [STRING]...
  or:  echo LONG-OPTION
Echo the STRING(s) to standard output.

  -n             do not output the trailing newline
  -e             enable interpretation of backslash escapes
  -E             disable interpretation of backslash escapes (default)
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

If -e is in effect, the following sequences are recognised:

  \\      backslash
  \a      alert (BEL)
  \b      backspace
  \c      produce no further output
  \e      escape
  \f      form feed
  \n      new line
  \r      carriage return
  \t      horizontal tab
  \v      vertical tab
  \0NNN   byte with octal value NNN (1 to 3 digits)
  \xHH    byte with hexadecimal value HH (1 to 2 digits)

NOTE: your shell may have its own version of echo, which usually supersedes
the version described here.  Please refer to your shell's documentation
for details about the options it supports.

Report echo bugs to bug-coreutils@gnu.org
GNU coreutils home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>
For complete documentation, run: info coreutils 'echo invocation'
--help
--help
```

The second and third `system` calls ran the builtin `echo`, which does not support the `--help` flag. The first ran `/bin/echo`, in my case provided by GNU, which did support the `--help` flag.

From [`man 3 system`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man3/system.3posix.html) (POSIX):

```
The environment of the executed command shall be as if a child  process
were created using fork(), and the child process invoked the sh utility
using execl() as follows:

      execl(<shell path>, "sh", "-c", command, (char *)0);
where <shell path> is an unspecified pathname for the sh utility.
```

And if you're on [Linux](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man3/system.3.html):

```
system()  executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c
command, and returns after the  command  has  been  completed.   During
execution  of  the  command,  SIGCHLD  will  be blocked, and SIGINT and
SIGQUIT will be ignored.
```

Since `/bin/sh -c` is used explicitly, you cannot influence it by any normal means - you could replace `/bin/sh`. That would be using a piledriver to pop bubblewrap.

Comment: I have an executable. I dont have a write permission to the C source code. All I can do is run that C program. But while running that C program I wish that `external echo` would be called instead of `build-in`.

Comment: @sps And why didn't you mention that in your question? Are we supposed to read your mind?

Comment: @sps In any case, then what you ask can't be done. Not without modifying the source.

Comment: sorry if it confused. i want to change something in the shell. not in the source code.

Comment: @sps Unless you can change `/bin/sh`, you're out of luck.

Comment: @muru - Given the posted source, and assuming the executable is dynamically linked and isn't setuid or setgid, you can use `LD_PRELOAD` to run your own `system()` function instead of the one in libc.so.  This would also be somewhat of a piledriver...

Comment: @AndrewHenle that sounds more workable than replacing `sh` - who knows what that will affect, at least with `LD_PRELOAD` we can assume only the OP's program will be affected. Perhaps you could post an answer?

Answer (score 3):

if you are using bash you can enable and disable a builtin shell commands using `enable`

`enable -n echo`

disables the builtin echo command.

Comment: It does the work for current shell. But when the c program runs in a new shell. So, .. is there a way that this setting will be there in child shell also ?

Comment: You should be able to run it before your command and end with a ```;```.

Comment: @phk no that doesnt work.

Comment: @sps, after some reading, it turns out that `system` uses `/bin/sh -c` to execute the command. is your `sh` a symbolic link to bash? (i was trying to test the usage of BASH_ENV in my system, but since /bin/sh is a link to dash, it doesn't work)

Comment: @adonis Same here. `/bin/sh: symbolic link to dash`

Answer (score 1):

<s>There is the `command` command for that.</s> Apparently, you can't.

BTW, be very careful with `system()` if you care about security issues.

Comment: How do I use  `command`? Please note that I am not asking about changing the source code. I am asking what configuration change I can make in the shell so that shell will use echo in `$PATH` instead of built-in.

Comment: Simply `command` and the command you want to execute on your `$PATH` or alternatively use `command -p <PATH>` to set a certain path.

Comment: -1: `command` bypasses functions and aliases, not builtins.

Comment: Oops, in that case I learned something new. Thank you!

Comment: ``system("`/usr/bin/which echo` Hello World");`` seems to work.